# Removing last line from QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using this bit of code to try to remove the last line from a QTextEdit:

```
    ui->textEdit_2->textCursor().setPosition( QTextCursor::End);
    auto k = ui->textEdit_2->textCursor().currentTable();
    k->removeRows(k->rows() - 1, 1);
```

but I get a segmentation fault. After debugging I found that that k is null when removeRows is called.

Am I doing something wrong? if yes, how can it be fixed?

Comment: According to Qt documentation, `QTextEdit::curentTable` returns 0 if the cursor is inside a block that is not part of a table. Does your text conatain _tables_ at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this (Tested):

```
ui->textEdit_2->setFocus();
QTextCursor storeCursorPos = ui->textEdit_2->textCursor();
ui->textEdit_2->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
ui->textEdit_2->moveCursor(QTextCursor::StartOfLine, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
ui->textEdit_2->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
ui->textEdit_2->textCursor().removeSelectedText();
ui->textEdit_2->textCursor().deletePreviousChar();
ui->textEdit_2->setTextCursor(storeCursorPos);
```

Comment: well spotted ui->textEdit_2->textCursor().deletePreviousChar();

Answer (score 2):

(Just leaving this undeleted to show another way of doing the same action)

You can try this to remove last line:

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit_2->textCursor();
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
cursor.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);
cursor.removeSelectedText();
cursor.deletePreviousChar(); // Added to trim the newline char when removing last line
ui->textEdit_2->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

If you want to restore cursor position to where it originally was, Just save the cursor position before calling

```
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
```

and then after removing text.

```
ui->textEdit_2->setTextCursor(savedCursorPos);
```

Comment: I tested your way, no effect? What's `savedCursorPos`?

Comment: forgot the setCursor(cursor) statement in the first block soz!!

Comment: @MM. you need to add the last line in the block as well. ui->textEdit_2->setTextCursor(cursor); for it to actually update.

Comment: That's a backup, taken with `auto savedCursorPos = ui->textEdit_2->textCursor();` before anything else. He probably found it obvious.

Comment: This sort of works but only once, as in removes 1 line and if I call it again nothing happens. Any ideas ?