# Programmatically edit the contents of a QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

How can I programmatically edit the contents of a QPlainTextEdit?

For example, I might want to implement a "Find and Replace", or remove a particular line of text, or insert some text.

The trivial approach would be to reload the contents entirely:

```
QString text = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
... // Now edit text.
ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);
```

However, this seems wasteful, and we will also lose any formatting added via `QPlainTextEdit::appendHtml()`.

Another approach is outlined in [Removing last line from QTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326569/removing-last-line-from-qtextedit) - they simulate the user editing the text. The answer is for QTextEdit, but I think it would work for QPlainTextEdit, as well:

```
ui->textEdit_2->setFocus();
QTextCursor storeCursorPos = ui->textEdit_2->textCursor();
ui->textEdit_2->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
ui->textEdit_2->moveCursor(QTextCursor::StartOfLine, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
ui->textEdit_2->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
ui->textEdit_2->textCursor().removeSelectedText();
ui->textEdit_2->textCursor().deletePreviousChar();
ui->textEdit_2->setTextCursor(storeCursorPos);
```

Which approach should I use to edit the contents? Does the second one have any advantages?

**Edit:** Is it even a valid approach, or just a hack?

Comment: You pretty much answered your question by yourself. Generally the second approach is more flexible. To add more to your answer, I would say you can control formatting, but also a text selection. It also makes any internal updates performed by `QPlainTextEdit` on a local, limited amount of text, not the entire contents (I would imagine, but I don't know what internal updates would those be).

Comment: @Googie What worried me was it looks like a hack. I guess I'm not sure if QPlainTextEdit was supposed to support programmatic editing at all.

Comment: Don't worry. It's perfectly fine and correct way to do this.

Comment: @Googie Thanks, that pretty much answers my  question, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QPlainTextEdit` documentation stands:

> Text can be inserted using the QTextCursor class or using the
>   convenience functions insertPlainText(), appendPlainText() or paste().

So it's a correct way to edit with `QTextCursor`.